# How to repair concrete damage from pulling up nail strips

Tags: concrete, slab

When pulling up carpet installed on a concrete slab, the wooden nail strip tracks often pull up sections of concrete and some of the concrete flakes off. I want to install an engineered floor on this slab so would like to repair this first. The good thing is this is limited to the edges of the room but those missing flakes  could cause leveling problems. How would you best repair this? I was thinking of using some grout to smooth over these areas. Also would you fill in all the nail holes left behind?

**Edit**: By flakes I mean large chunks pulled up between the nails, some 5 inches long and 3 inches wide.

Comment: The engineered wood floor will cover those holes. If the areas are broken and raised up, then break them loose and sweep up the fragments to make a hole.

Answer (score 3):

Those small dimples are unlikely to ever be a problem, but if you want peace of mind, get some vinyl repair patch material and skim it on with a wide putty knife or trowel.

Comment: I edited my post: By flakes I mean large chunks pulled up between the nails, some 5 inches long.

Comment: Answer still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use vynl cement. It is weak and brittle. Use cement all by rapid set. If the patches are small save a few dollars and buy an already mixed cement at home depot

Comment: Vinyl patch is recommended specifically because the vinyl polymer additive makes it more flexible and bond better. Also, premixed cements don't tend to bond as well or cure as quickly. They're water-based, and therefore must dry to harden. True cement products cure to harden, chemically bonding with the water.